# Problem with params 301 redirects in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters, http-status-code-301

Another question. How we can redirect this URL:

https://www.example.com/index.php?cl=contact

The following doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cl=contact
RewriteRule index\.php https://www.example.com/contact [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

That redirection rule *should* work, though it certainly can be optimized:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cl=contact$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ https://www.example.com/contact [R=301]
```

So your actual issue has to be something else. You will need to check these things:

- is the rewriting module loaded at all into the http server?
- is rewriting permitted at all for that location inside the http host (see the `AllowOverride` command)
- do you see anything that might be related in your http server's error log files?
- if you are using a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), is it located at the correct location (inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder)?
- is that configuration actually readable for the http server process?
- is that request actually processed in the http host where the rule is implemented?

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE:

Considering the additional information you gave in the comment this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cl=contact$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ https://www.example.com/contact [R=301,QSD]
```

As the documentation states the [`QSD`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag deletes the query string during the rewriting process.

If that also does not work then again chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try this variant:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cl=contact$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ https://www.example.com/contact? [R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, sorry u're right!
My request was another one: The script adds the parameters to the new forwarded link: https://www.example.com/contact?cl=contact

But we need the redirected link without the parameters

Comment: I added a _third_ variant too ;-)

Comment: "Doesn't work" has never helped anyone anywhere. What does that mean? Please add _a few_ more details.

Comment: The output of both variants is still https://www.example.com/contact?cl=contact

Comment: Please make sure that you are not looking at a result cached on the client side. I mentioned that referring to the 302 redirection during implementation.

Comment: We check the result with redirect-checker.org Should be not cached, or?

Comment: I have no idea. Why don't you simply clear your cache or use a new anonymous tab.

Comment: It might also be that you have another redirection rule hidden somewhere, one that is processed before this rule. You can check that (also the cache) by altering the redirection to some other (non existing) path. What happens?